# Python has stopped working while adding sizer in scrolled panel in wxpython

Tags: python-3.6, wxwidgets, wxpython

```
import wx
import wx.adv
from wx.lib.masked import NumCtrl
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel
import wx.lib.masked as masked
from wx.lib.masked import Field, BaseMaskedTextCtrl


class mainWindow(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, camera):


    #inheritence
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN, size=(1370,720),pos=(0,0))
    self.Title = "Registration"
    self.SetSize(1370,720)
    self.Maximize(True)
    self.SetBackgroundColour('#f0f0f0')
    menubar = wx.MenuBar()


    #main ui
    self.mainpanel = wx.Panel(self, size=(1370,720), pos=(0,0))
    self.mainpanel.SetBackgroundColour('#f0f0f0')


    mid_font = wx.Font(22, wx.DECORATIVE,wx.ITALIC,wx.BOLD)
    #------------form panel-------------

    self.scroll_panel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self.mainpanel,size=(380,540), pos=(30,20),style=wx.NO_BORDER)

    self.namepanel = wx.Panel(self.scroll_panel,size=(350,800), pos=(0,0),style=wx.DOUBLE_BORDER)
    self.namepanel.SetForegroundColour('#1b262c')

    self.Sizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
    self.scroll_panel.SetSizer(self.Sizer)


    small_font = wx.Font(11, wx.DECORATIVE,wx.ITALIC,wx.BOLD)


    fname = wx.StaticText(self.namepanel, -1, "First Name",pos=(30,70))
    fname.SetFont(small_font)
    self.fname = wx.TextCtrl(self.namepanel, pos=(155,70), size=(160, 25))

    mname = wx.StaticText(self.namepanel, -1, "Middle Name",pos=(30,110))
    mname.SetFont(small_font)
    self.mname = wx.TextCtrl(self.namepanel, pos=(155,110), size=(160, 25))

    lname = wx.StaticText(self.namepanel, -1, "Last Name",pos=(30,150))
    lname.SetFont(small_font)
    self.lname = wx.TextCtrl(self.namepanel, pos=(155,150), size=(160, 25))



    button_font = wx.Font(12, wx.DECORATIVE,wx.NORMAL,wx.BOLD)
    self.add = wx.Button(self.namepanel, -1, "Confirm", pos=(110,200),size=(130, 30),style=wx.DOUBLE_BORDER)
    #self.add.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.addinfo)

    self.add.SetBackgroundColour('#FFFFFF')
    self.add.SetForegroundColour('#1b262c')
    self.add.SetFont(button_font)

    self.Sizer.Add( self.namepanel, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.scroll_panel.SetupScrolling(scrollToTop=False)






class all_module(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self):


    #inheritence
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN,pos=(0,0))

    self.infopanel = wx.Panel(self,size=(1000,780), pos=(0, 0),style=wx.DOUBLE_BORDER)

    self.registration = wx.Button(self.infopanel, -1, "Registration", pos=(0,0),size=(130, 30),style=wx.DOUBLE_BORDER)
    self.registration.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.register)



  def register(self, event):

      window = mainWindow(camera)
      window.Show()





app = wx.App()
window = all_module()
window.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

This is our code in which there is a simple registration **scrolled panel** and it is added in **boxsizer**. when i press close button i got this error that python has stopped working. but when i remove the sizer and i place all **static text** and **textctrl** out side the sizer, the program closes smoothly. But if i add in sizer i got the error i tried all the ways like **self.Close()** and **self.Destroy()** but nothing has worked. Any suggestion would be appreciated for us, Thanks in advance!!

> Python has stopped working

.

[image]

Comment: Use the command line to debug i.e. `python myprogram.py`. What is `camera`? address that first.

Comment: Do you think `Sizer` is a good name for a `Sizer`?

Comment: You haven't replied, so less cryptically, rename `self.Sizer` to be `self.MySizer` throughout, replace `camera` with `None` and see what happens.